# Databricks notebook read tables with R

Tags: r, databricks

I'm trying to read a table in a databricks notebook with R.

i.e. this is the table:
[image: this is the table]

I can read the table with magic commands

With Python...

```
%python
dat = spark.sql('Select * from sandbox_did_sio_phernandez.ESM_T_DL_Eventos5')
display(dat)
```

and with SQL...

```
%sql
FROM sandbox_did_sio_phernandez.ESM_T_DL_Eventos5 SELECT * AS df
```

but idk how to move the table to R (or read directly with R).

The command:

```
df = read.df("some url", source = "delta", header="true", inferSchema = "true")
```

don't work, because in my company we can't use delta tables anymore, only the data form.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can consider the following :

```
library(SparkR)
dat <- SparkR::sql('Select * from sandbox_did_sio_phernandez.ESM_T_DL_Eventos5')
```